# Bash bug re $LINENO-- or am I just confused?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Consider:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo '
' $LINENO
echo '' '
'  $LINENO
```

The first echo correctly prints a 4, but the second echo prints a 5 instead of 6.  Am I missing something, or is this a bug?  (Using bash 3.00.15)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like an implementation misfeature (bug) in bash.

I used:

```
#!/bin/bash -p
echo $LINENO
echo ' ' $LINENO '
' $LINENO '
' $LINENO
echo '' '
'  $LINENO
```

which yielded:

```
2
  3 
 3 
 3

 6
```

Which supports the theory that the variable is evaluated before the shell considers the line to have been completed. Once the line has been completed, it updates the LINENO and proceeds.

Bash versions tested: 3.2.48 (mac), 4.1.5 (linux)

When I use the syntax:

```
echo '
' $LINENO
```

it gets the newer line number. It seems to be related to the evaluation of the empty string carried as the only argument on the line.

Comment: zsh does appear to have the misfeature. It yielded the exact same output.

Comment: However, zsh still seems to handle line numbers better than Bash in process substitutions. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/pawamoy/cca35f0f5ccd56665d6421e9b2d2d4bc)

Answer (score 3):

`Bash` seems to interpret a multi-string & multi-line argument to the `echo` command to be on just one line of the source code file (script) because `Bash` has to concatenate the multi-string & multi-line argument to the `echo` command into a single (one line) argument. The concatenation mechanism is also triggered by an empty string `''` followed by a string containing a newline character `echo -e '' + '\n' + $LINENO`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash concatenates a multi-string & multi-line argument ...
echo ' ' $LINENO '
' $LINENO '
' $LINENO

# ... into a one line argument.
echo -e "' ' $LINENO '\n' $LINENO '\n' $LINENO\n"
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "2
3
4
5
6 LINENO: $LINENO"   # 6 LINENO: 6
exit
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "2" " " "
3
4
5
6 LINENO: $LINENO"   # 6 LINENO: 2
# echo -e "2" + " " + "\n3\n4\n5\n6 LINENO: $LINENO"
exit
```