# Can you enhance error handling with Mac Terminal using set -e?

Tags: macos, bash, error-handling, terminal

I am trying to make a simple command (preferably using set -e) to stop my scripts when an error is hit. As it stands using solely set -e it works..b ut you are stuck with the generic "blah blah nto found or directory doesnt exist" error message.

Is there a simple way to have it also spit out at least the $LINENO line where the script died? Any other advice is also welcoem and appreicated! Thank you everyone! :)

Answer (score 1):

Set a trap on the EXIT pseudo-signal:

```
trap '(( $? > 0 )) && printf "Error on line $LINENO\n"' EXIT
```

This ensures that the error message is only printed if the script is going to exit with a non-zero exit status.

Comment: beautiful, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much Chepner. @ all else, recommendations / tips are of course still welcome for learning sake!

Comment: @chepner This does in fact work, but after testing several scenarios I am noticing that it always prints "Error on Line 2" no matter where I break the script. Apologies if this is a silly question as I am rather new to bash. :)

Comment: Are you using the same types of quotes? If the first argument to `trap` uses double quotes, then `$LINENO` is expanded when the trap is defined, not when the trap is triggered.

Comment: I am using the exact as you showed above. So to my understanding (I think!) the trap argument is using single quotes, and $LINENO should be expanded when trap is defined.

Comment: after some testing it actually looks like bash is concatenating multi-string and multi-line arguements into one line for some reason

Comment: I also found some very useful information at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360929/bash-bug-re-lineno-or-am-i-just-confused . I wonder if there is a good way to work around this?